# Click next without having to fill out all required fields but not submit until all required fields are filled out

Tags: cognito-forms

Do you know of any way that someone can click next without having to fill out all required fields but not be able to click submit until all required fields are filled out?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a script that hides (or disables) the submit button on load, then checks through all the required fields each time a field is changed (through an event listener). After that check, if none of the required fields has a null value, enable the submit button.

As Nadia indicates, this would be outside of the scope of Cognito's built-in features.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible because a user must fill in all required fields on a page before they can continue onto the next page.